# Show recent posts from one category on a non-WP site

Tags: categories, get-posts

I'm trying to move back to WP for our blog, after struggling with a clunky CMS for a few years, but we'll be sticking with that CMS for the rest of the site. Is there a plugin (or code) that I can use to pull the recent posts in a particular category from my WP blog to the sidebar of my non-WP site? Assume full permissions on both the WP blog and the external site.

Comment: Like http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45039/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-latest-posts-outside-of-my-wp-install, but with categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to just use a PHP based reader and parse/output the results. Maybe your CMS already has one but if not and it's based on PHP you can use,

- [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)
- [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)
- [Simplexml](https://www.php.net/simplexml)

Then you simple point it to your categories /feed, like  --> `www.example.com/your_category/feed`

You can easily customize a feed to show whatever you want http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

That way you can have a feed that only shows recent posts from one category using [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you just have to point your reader to it.

Alternatives you can try via a plugin that allow for external HTTP requests:

[Hookpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hookpress/)
[JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/)

Comment: My organization is pretty skeptical of RSS integration with our site -- apparently they tried it a while back and it was slow and unreliable. Other options?

Comment: There is nothing particular slow about a feed since it's completely in your control. A good alternative is hookpress or a json API. I'll add them as links to the above.